# Irreducible characters of SU(3)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

There is a simple formula for the irreducible characters of  SU(2), 
$$ 
\chi^{(j)} (\theta) = \frac{\sin (j+\frac{1}{2})\theta}{\sin \frac{1}{2}\theta},
$$
where the irreps have dimensionality $( 2 j +1)\times(2j+1)$.

Is there a similar formula for the characters of the irreps of SU(3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in fact there is! The formula for the character of the irreducible representation of $SU(3)$ with [highest weight $(p,q)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Representations_of_the_SU(3)_group) is

\begin{align}
\chi^{p,q}(\theta, \phi) 
=
e^{i \theta (p+2q)}\sum\limits_{k=q}^{p+q}\sum\limits_{l=0}^q e^{-3i(k+l) \theta/2} 
\left(\frac{\sin((k-l+1)\phi/2)}{\sin (\phi/2)} \right)
\end{align}

For example, one can check that the defining representation (highest weight $(1,0)$) has

\begin{align}
\chi^{1,0}(\theta, \phi) 
&=
e^{i \theta}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1}\sum\limits_{l=0}^0 e^{-3i(k+l) \theta/2} 
\left(\frac{\sin((k-l+1)\phi/2)}{\sin (\phi/2)} \right)
\\
&=
e^{i \theta}+e^{i(\phi-\theta)/2} + e^{-i(\phi+\theta)/2}
\end{align}

which as expected is just the trace of some $U \in SU(3)$ in terms of two independent eigenvalues, where the three eigenvalues are related to each other by $\det U =1$.

An equivalent formula is also given in [Baaquie's paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/21/11/022/pdf) (Equations 3.1 and 3.2):

\begin{align}
\chi^{p,q}(x,y) 
&=
-\frac{i}{s(x,y)}
\big(
- e^{i ((p+1) y - (q+1) x)} 
+ e^{i ((p+1) x - (q+1) y)}
\\
&+ e^{-i (p+1) (x+y)} (e^{-i (q+1) x} - e^{-i (q+1) y}) 
+ e^{i (q+1) (x+y)}(e^{i (p+1) y} - e^{i (p+1) x}) 
\big)
\\
s(x,y) 
&= 
8 \sin \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) 
\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (x+2 y)\right) 
\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 x+y)\right)
\end{align}

---

This actually took me longer to sort out than is ideal, so here I document some things to note in case there is confusion for others in future.

- A derivation of $\chi^{p,q}(\theta, \phi) $ can be found in Chapter 10.15 of [Greiner - Quantum Mechanics: Symmetries (2nd revised edition)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642579769). There is a typo in the final quoting of the result - in Equation 10.121 the first $\varphi$ should instead be a $\psi$. If anyone knows a a mathematics textbook that explicitly writes down the $SU(3)$ result, I'd appreciate a message about it!
- [The characters of $Gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ are the Schur polynomials](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/schur-polynomials/), then one needs to specialize to the subgroup $SU(n)$. This is effectively what is carried out in the cited derivation, although written more from the perspective of physicists and specialized to the case $n=3$.
- The result is also quoted [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9604029). Typos also appear: in Equations 5.65 and 5.82, $m_{12}$ is almost surely meant to be $m_{13}$.
- On notation: irreducible representations of $SU(n)$ each have a corresponding [Young Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Diagrams) with at most $n-1$ rows. One then chooses to uniquely label the irreducible representation according $n-1$ non-negative integers $(q_1,\dots, q_{n-1})$ where $q_i$ is the number of boxes in row $i$ in the diagram (counting from the top down), **or** one labels the irreducible representation according to $(p_1,\dots,p_{n-1}) := (q_1-q_2,q_2-q_3, \dots,q_{n-2}-q_{n-1},q_{n-1})$, where now $p_i$ gives the total number of columns of length $i$ in the diagram. The $h_{ij}$'s and $m_{ij}$'s that appear respectively in Greiner and Prakash's derivations correspond to the $q_i$'s, whereas the $p_i$'s correspond to the labeling in for example [Brian Hall's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319134666) (that book uses $(p_1,p_2) = (m_1,m_2)$). I have converted the formula to use the $p_i$ labeling in my answer above, which to be explicit corresponds to $(p,q) = (p_1,p_2)$ and for example the $(p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)/2$ [dimension formula for the irreducible representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Representations_of_the_SU(3)_group). Baaquie's paper uses the convention (2, 1) for (p, q) of the fundamental representation, so you need to subtract 1 from each of his weights to get the more standard convention that I used. I have already done this in the formula above.

---

Edit: The formula is now correctly described as applying to SU(3) in particular, and not for SU(n) in general.

Comment: I really appreciate all the details you have provided (I assume you updated the Wikipedia article also!). One clarification though: the formula you have written is for SU(3) and not SU(*n*), right?

Comment: No problem! Yes I updated the wikipedia article. Yes, it's all for $SU(3)$ specifically. For $SU(n)$ there would need to be $n-1$ integers to specify the irreducible representations.

Comment: Oh I see! Yes indeed, the original version of my answer had a typo, thanks for correcting.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.